# How to Drag and Drop Images Into other imageview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-imageview, touchimageview

I have 5 ImageViews . Now i want to perform drag and drop feature between them.

i don't know how to perform this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop

Comment: Thanks  successfully Done